# Two divs keep switching place - How do I stop this?

Tags: html, css

I have three divs in a column format that have widths as a percent of the window. Once the screen gets to 1300 px or less, I want the two rightmost divs to stop getting smaller and basically overtake the leftmost div (there will be content in the right and middle divs but nothing in the left one). I made a media query that says when the screen gets to 1300px, the left div's width becomes 0, and the middle and right have fixed widths and float right. However, when I do this, the middle and right divs always switch places so that the middle one is all the way to the right and the right one jumps to the left of the middle. How do I stop the two divs from switching places?

I have tried changing the display of the divs to block or inline but nothing has worked.

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left {
 width: 20%;
 background-color: red;
}

.middle {
 width:60%;
 background-color: orange;
}

.right {
 width:20%;
 background-color: yellow;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
 .left {
  width: 0px;
 }
 .middle {
  width:765px;
  float: right;
 }
 .right {
  width: 255px;
  float: right;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
 <div class="column left"></div>
 <div class="column middle">
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum </h3>
 </div>
 <div class="column right">
  <div class="form-box"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

After the window becomes less than 1300px, I just want the middle and right columns to float right with the middle one to the left of the right one, but instead they always switch places.

Comment: Why do you want to switch from float:left to float:right? Unless you're trying to have an empty space to the left of the middle & right divs on narrower screens you could just set your widths in the media query and be done with it.

Comment: @JohnB That is what I wanted. There is going to be a form in the right margin that I want to stay in the margin and I wanted the left margin to appear to collapse (the colors were just for me to see where everything was, and would not be on the live page)

Comment: That makes sense. The behaviour you're seeing is expected - the middle div comes first in the code, so when it's floated to the right it gets to go first, then after that's done the "right" div goes as far to the right as it can, in this case to the left of the middle div. You could try floating everything to the right from the beginning, or look at flexbox or CSS grid solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be better suited using `flexbox` to do what you are trying to do. Also, you used the CSS class `.column` instead of the `.columns` definition you have in your css.

Try this:

```css
.columns {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
}

.left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}

.middle {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: orange;
}

.right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: yellow;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .left {
    display: none;
  }
  .middle {
    width: 500px;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
  .right {
    width: 500px;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
  }
}

/*@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .middle {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}*/
```

```html
<div class="columns">
 <div class="column left"></div>
 <div class="column middle">
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum </h3>
 </div>
 <div class="column right">
  <div class="form-box"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try flexbox. The thing is that I need the middle and right divs to stop shrinking after the media query, which is why I cancelled the left box so that they could eat its space as the window got smaller (up to a point). I also styled "column" on purpose because that is a class of each column, while "columns" was the class of the div containing the three columns (which I hadn't styled at all)

Comment: I changed my code to make the columns stop shrinking after the media query, if thats what you were trying to do.